# How does a user register with Oauth?

Tags: php, oauth

I have been doing research on this Oauth concept and I am still very confused about this concept. One of my main questions is how does one register with a google account or a twitter account.

For example, lets say in order to register to my website, you must provide a Username/Password/Email/GroupName. If you register through my website, than you can provide those fields very easily. However let's say the user wants to register through google. How would those fields populate?

From my understanding once you register with your google credentials, you are redirected to a page on my website where you fill in the required fields. I am not sure if this is correct. Can anyone help me understand this more?

Comment: Which Oauth are you speaking about. There are different ones, and it also is considered to be broken.

Comment: If you are authenticating with Oauth why do you need a username and password? For Email and group, you would need a separate registration page. With a Google account you can get an email address, but other Oauth accounts may not have one available.

Comment: @hakra OAuth is *not* broken, it can be used securely if implemented right. It has its downsides and complexities though, as almost every standard that takes account of lots of use cases.

Comment: @JanGerlinger: I wrote "is considered broken", just quoting a giving up lead. It still rots there, so you can say it still lives and actually does work for the one or other case.

Comment: Usually OAuth bypasses the signing up process entirely, that is, you don't get username/password/email/whatever but instead a token string that represents "yes, this user is correctly logged in, please go on and do your magic". Some like google or facebook may allow fetching the email address afterwards through their own API, but that won't be via OAuth.

Comment: @hakra OAuth or OpenID is considered broken? don't mix the two :) OAuth as a protocol is still effectively used by Facebook, twitter, google, etc for single sign on purposes afaik.

Comment: So basically once the user is logged in via google/fb/etc I would have to handle the rest of my information myself?

Comment: @Mahn: [OAuth 2.0](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/)

Answer (score 15):

Basically OAuth works like this (depending on the version these points consist of multiple steps):

- You redirect the user to a provider, where he logs in
- The user is redirected back to you and you receive an **access token**

Using this **access token** you can then request the users data from the provider. Typically the providers provide a call which you can use to ask for the user's email address, full name and a (provider-specific) **user id**, but that is not part of OAuth.

How you now use this information to handle that user as if he logged in to your site is then completely on your own. You probably want to create a new user object on your side each time you see a new **user id**.

Comment: O i see. So if im understanding correctly, Once a user logs in with their google email/password I then have to redirect them to my own page where they fill in the rest of the credentials?

Comment: @user1436497 you could, but that would make a bad UX.

Answer (score 8):

There are couple of basic concepts that needs some clarity before one can understand how a new user registration happens using OAuth2. These are:

- Resource Owner (You, the human)
- Identity Provider (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.)
- Resource Server (Same as Identity provider, or some other service)
- Resources (Things you want access to)
- Client app (The app you are using to access those things)

For new user registration, you will follow the same sequence of client app requesting authorization to be granted access to the resources. This will trigger a login page, user logs in, authorization code is created (by the IdP) and sent back to the client app. The client app exchanges this code for an access token (some encryption signing is involved, read up the documentation - basically allowing client app to prove its own identify).

This access token is then used to request access to resources - in this case, the new user profile. This could be name, email, picture etc. Use this to create a new row in your client apps profile database. A new user account is created.

Then for subsequent logins, the client app will use this access token to validate its life with the Google Auth server - and then create a local session/cookie to login the user.

Hope this is clear.